# if list item is false add it only once in another list

Tags: java, arraylist, conditional-statements

I have a class:

```
public class myObj {

    private boolean liesIn;
    private String Area;

  public myObj(){

  }


  public myObj(boolean liesIn, String Area) {
      super();
      this.liesIn = liesIn;
      this.Area = Area;
      }


  public boolean isLiesIn() {
      return liesIn;
  }

  public void setLiesIn(boolean liesIn) {
      this.liesIn = liesIn;
  }

  public String getArea() {
      return Area;
  }

  public void setArea(String Area) {
      this.Area = Area;
  }

}
```

I am filling a list with these objects:

```
 List<myObj> results = new ArrayList<myObj>();     

 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    myObj theObj = new myObj();
    theObj.setLiesIn(condition);

    if (condition) {
      theObj.setArea(Areas.values()[i].name());
      results.add(theObj);

     } else {
        theObj.setArea("No area");
        results.add(theObj);
     }
```

}

Now, the problem is that, for example, I may have one true and 9 falses and at the exit (when I return the results) , I am getting all the results/objects  like:

```
[
{
"liesIn": false,
"Area": "No area" 
},

{
 "liesIn": false,
"Area": "No area" 
},
{
"liesIn": true,
"Area": "Area13" 
},
{
"liesIn": false,
"Area": "No area" 
},
{
 "liesIn": true,
"Area": "Area14" 
},



....
]
```

So, if I have true values , I only want to show them.There is no meaning to show the false values.

If all values are false, I want to show only one result.

I thought to create a new results List and use an iterator in the old list:

```
 List<myObj> newresults = new ArrayList<myObj>();

 Iterator<myObj> iter = results.iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
   myObj lies = iter.next();

   if (lies.isLiesIn() == true) {
          newresults.add(lies);
   } else {
          // add only 1 object with false value (no area)    
   }

 }
```

So, I am not sure how to deal with the last piece of code.Maybe there is another way to do it.I thought of using copy in order to copy the `results` into the `newresults` but again I can't handle the else statement.

Comment: You can just go over the list, if there is at least one true value - copy it over. If there isn't any true item, after the loop copy one item in random (let's say index 0) over - since they're all false, and there's no need to select one in particular. I wrote an answer with code below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a problem - all you need to do is:

```
List<myObj> newresults = new ArrayList<myObj>();

 Iterator<myObj> iter = results.iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
   myObj lies = iter.next();
   if (lies.isLiesIn() == true) {
          newresults.add(lies);
   }
 }
 // if no true element was added - the list contained only false
 if (newresults.size()==0 && results.size()>0) {
     newresults.add(results.get(0));
 }
```

Comment: Nice!It works,thanks.I can't understand the last part though `newresults.add(results.get(0));`.Here, we add to the new list the result from the first list (results) at position 0.But, how can we be sure that the `results.get(0)` is false??Since, it is already filled.

Comment: Results was scanned through in the iteration - so we know all the items are false, since the iteration did not copy over a single entry. So all the items in results are false - including the one in the 0 index. We copy just one to the new list to represent a false for all the rest.